# Ignore all bin and obj directories

Tags: svn

I've just built my csproj and now have `bin` and `obj` directories throughout my subversion checkout. How do I ignore both of those directories no matter where they are located?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ignorePatterns.txt` file with the following lines.

```
bin
obj
```

Then run this from the root directory of the local checkout of the repository.

```
svn propset -R svn:ignore . -F .\ignorePatterns.txt
```